# On/Off switch android studio

Tags: android, audio

I have a on/off switch called audio_switch. In my MainActivity file I want to look if the switch is on, if so, it should set a variable audio = 1. This piece of code mentioned can be found at the bottom of my MainActivity. On the very top after you can see I added a line to find my audio file. A few lines later I used an if(audio == 1) statement to check if the switch is on, so it will play the audio. This however does not work, it does however when I change the statement to audio == audio

```
package com.joeridukker.main;

import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static int audio;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MediaPlayer MansNotHot = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mans_not_hot);

        if(audio == 1){
            MansNotHot.start();
        }

        int secondsDelayed = 1;
        Handler start = new Handler();
        start.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Animation wait = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.wait);
                ConstraintLayout Entire = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.Entire);
                ImageView Logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Logo);
                TextView Welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome);
                Welcome.startAnimation(wait);
                Entire.startAnimation(wait);
                Logo.startAnimation(wait);
                // Actions to do after 10 seconds
            }
        }, 0);
        Handler animation = new Handler();
        animation.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.fade_and_slide_upwards);
                Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.fade_and_slide_downwards);
                TextView Welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome);
                ImageView Logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Logo);
                Logo.startAnimation(slide_down);
                Welcome.startAnimation(slide_up);

                // Actions to do after 10 seconds
            }
        }, 500);

        Handler entire_animation = new Handler();
        entire_animation.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                Animation fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.fade_in);
                ConstraintLayout Entire = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.Entire);
                TextView Welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome);
                Entire.startAnimation(fade_in);
                ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
                        Welcome,
                        "textColor",
                        new ArgbEvaluator(),
                        Color.argb(140,0,0,0),
                        Color.WHITE
                ).setDuration(500)
                        .start();
            }
        }, 500);




        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Handler splash = new Handler();
                int a = 1;
                Intent Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Differentiate.class);
                Intent.putExtra("HEADER", a);
                startActivity(Intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_switch_fast,R.anim.fade_out_switch_fast);
                finish();
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 2500);
    }
    public static class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragment {



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

            //Check the current value in preference.
            SharedPreferences switchPrefStatus = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean switchPrefValue = switchPrefStatus.getBoolean("audio_switch", false);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Current value: " + switchPrefValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Preference switchPref = (Preference) findPreference("audio_switch");
            switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                    boolean isOn = (boolean) o;
                    //Do what you want with the value!:)
                    if (isOn) {
                        audio = 1;

                    }else{
                        audio = 0;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My SettingsActivity

```
package com.joeridukker.main;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings. On
 * handset devices, settings are presented as a single list. On tablets,
 * settings are split by category, with category headers shown to the left of
 * the list of settings.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 */
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();


            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
                // using RingtoneManager.
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                    preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                        preference.setSummary(null);
                    } else {
                        // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                        // name.
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                // simple string representation.
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    static int audio;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            Preference switchPref = (Preference) findPreference("audio_switch");

            switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

                    boolean isOn = (boolean) o;

                    if (isOn) {
                        audio = 1;


                    }else{
                        audio = 0;

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I look in MainActivity if the switch is on